# Processing 3 - Calling draw() from a function doesn't update the screen

Tags: screen, processing, draw, updating

I'm experimenting with how to process some data in one function while displaying a loading bar on the screen. For an example, I'm adding a bunch of values to an array - a process that takes about 5 seconds on my computer. I have the following code:

```java
ArrayList<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();
String state;
float counter;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480);
  state = "load";
  noStroke();
}

void draw() {
  if (state.equals("load")) {
    load();
  } else if (state.equals("loading")) {
    background(255);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(0, height/2-25, map(counter, 0, 10000000, 0, width), 50);
  } else if (state.equals("play")) {
    background(0, 255, 0);
  }
}

void load() {
  state = "loading";
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    strs.add(str(pow(i, 2)));

    if (i % 1000 == 0) {
      counter = i;
      draw();
    }
  }
  state = "play";
}
```

But I just get a grey screen (indicating that background(255) has never been called) for about 5 seconds until I get a green screen. I could, of course, replace the code with something like:

```java
ArrayList<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();
String state;
int counter;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480);
  state = "load";
  noStroke();
  counter = 0;
}

void draw() {
  if (state.equals("load")) {
    float theMillis = millis();
    while (millis()-theMillis < 1000.0/frameRate && counter < 10000000) {
      strs.add(str(pow(counter, 2)));
      counter++;
    }
    if (counter >= 10000000) {
      state = "play";
    }

    background(255);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(0, height/2-25, map(counter, 0, 10000000, 0, width), 50);
  } else if (state.equals("play")) {
    background(0, 255, 0);
  }
}
```

And that would work for this simple example, but I am trying to get draw() to work when called from a function explicitly as depending on the complexity of load() (the one I'm actually trying to get to work in my project is 250+ lines long of opening and uncompressing files, processing JSONArrays and ArrayLists, etc.) splitting the load function into chunks inside draw() could be a nightmare. So is there anyway to update the screen from inside a function?

Thanks in advance for all your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're discovering, Processing does not actually update the screen until the `draw()` function completes. So what's happening is the `draw()` function is called by Processing, and inside that frame, you happen to be calling the `draw()` function yourself. But that first call to `draw()` hasn't completed yet, so the screen is not updated. It's only updated when all of your calls to `draw()` are done, and the very first call (which Processing made) completes.

Calling `draw()` yourself like this is usually a pretty bad idea. You should usually use a variable that you update over time to change what's displaying each frame.

Another option is to use a separate thread to load your file, that way the drawing thread can continue.

Comment: I tried adding `noLoop()` at the start of `load()` and `loop()` at the end, and it didn't seem to change anything - and that way there is no way for `draw()` to be already running when I call it...

Comment: @VladimirShevyakov Calling `noLoop()` and `loop()` will not change the fact that the first call to `draw()` has not yet completed.

Comment: Ah. Well I actually just managed to solve to problem using `thread()`

Comment: @VladimirShevyakov Yes, that's what my last sentence was getting at. But please note that if you're sharing data between threads, you have to be extra careful.